# PHP join two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays and I would like to join them. Both arrays are a product of a foreach loop. The first one being:

```
$cleanNums[] = array(
    '01'=>$numbers[1],
    '02'=>$numbers[2],
    '03'=>$numbers[3],
    '04'=>$numbers[4],
    '05'=>$numbers[5],
    );
```

and the second one being:

```
$newDates[] = array(
    'day'=>$cleanDate[1],
    'month'=>$cleanDate[2],
    'year'=>$cleanDate[3],
    'draw'=>$cleanDate[6],
    );
```

Using array_merge `$weeklyValues = array_merge($newDates,$cleanNums);` I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 1st
            [month] => March
            [year] => 2017
            [draw] => 660
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [01] => 3
            [02] => 23
            [03] => 40
            [04] => 20
            [05] => 28
        )
)
```

I would like my output to read as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 1st
            [month] => March
            [year] => 2017
            [draw] => 660
            [01] => 3
            [02] => 23
            [03] => 40
            [04] => 20
            [05] => 28
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
$resultArray = array(
    0 => current($newDates) + current($cleanNums)
);

print_r($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `array_merge` is the way to do it http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php. The reason for incorrect output is in the way you define variables e.g.

`$cleanNums[] = array(...)`

Will result in nested array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
   ...
  }
}
```

To avoid it either change the way of the assignment:

```
$cleanNums = array(...)
```

Or the way how you provide it as `array_merge` parameters:

```
$weeklyValues = array_merge($newDates[0],$cleanNums[0]);
```

The same needs to be applied for `$newDates` of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $cleanNums and $newDates are multidimensional arrays and will get more [] values;

```
$weeklyValues = array();

foreach($cleanNums as $array)
{
    $weeklyValues = array_merge($weeklyValues,$array);
}

foreach($newDates as $array)
{
    $weeklyValues = array_merge($weeklyValues,$array);
}

print_r($weeklyValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($newDates);
$mergedArray = array();
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
   //assuming both arrays have equal number of records
   $mergedArray[] = current($newDates[$i]) + current($cleanNums[$i]);
}
var_dump($mergedArray);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.